# Can you describe what is $S^1 \times [0,\infty)$?

Tags: general-topology

Can you describe what is $S^1 \times$ [0,$\infty)$? Where "$\times$" stands for the product topology and the two factors are with the euclidean topology.

EDIT: What about $S^1 \times S^1$?

Comment: It's a half-infinite cylinder.

Comment: Think of an infinite tube or an infinitely long hose.  Now cut it in half (i.e., anywhere).

Comment: What exactly are you looking for that the description "S^1 \times [0, \infty)$ doesn't already give you?

Comment: It is the same as the closed unit disc minus the origin.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel What about $S^1 \times S^1$?

Comment: A torus. ${}{}$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel What is the intuition behind that? Why do I have to sum all the different circumferences to make the torus?

Comment: @LudovicoBessi the intuition behind that is that a torus has a large circle, with on each point $x\in S^1$, a smaller circle around $x$. By specifying a point $(x,y)\in S^1 \times S^1$ you first pick your $x$ as a point on the large circle, and $y\in S^1$ on the small circle.

Comment: @LudovicoBessi in the future, add some details to your question. *What* is confusing? *What* are you looking for-- is it formally topological, geometric, etc.? What kind of intuition would be helpful, and finally the last question in your most recent comment does not make much sense. Adding that to the main body of the question would help users  gather where you are in your understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to think of the cross product, is that at each point in the first factor, you are attaching a copy of the second space.

For example: $S^1 \times \{s\}$, where $s$ is a single point, is really just $S^1$, since at each point you are replacing it with a different point.

$S^1 \times \{s,t\}$ is a two copies of the circle. You can view this by taking a circle, and at each point, you are replacing it with two points, and looking at the full collection of these gives two circles.

Actually, $S^1 \times \{1, \dots, n\}$ is nothing but $n$ circles, and $S^1 \times \mathbb Z$ is a countable collection of circles. You can visualize them as stacked along some verticle axis, with a circle at each integer.

Going further, $S^1 \times \mathbb R$ is a circle, but whenever there was a point, you replace it with a line, so you get a circle of lines, or in other words, a cylinder.

$S^1 \times [a,\infty)$ is the same, but with a half open interval.

$S^1 \times S^1$ is a circle of circles, so at each point you attach a circle (for the sake of visualization, say you attach a circle with smaller radius), then you get a torus, with  the traditional donut visual.

Comment: Addendum, this point of view lends itself well to one generalization of the cross product, known as a fiber bundle. Maybe just an idea to be aware of. One such example would be a mobius band, which looks kind of like $S^1 \times [0,1]$, but with a twist.